# Missing query string parameters after submitting form via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to submit a form whenever the selected value is changes, and add query string parameter. It can only submit, but the parameter is lost. For example, when submitted, I want to submit the form to this url:

http://www.example.com/myblog?year=2012

But the url below is actually submitted, with parameter missing:

http://www.example.com/myblog

It works if I change to submit to google.com.

Any idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#newsArchiveDropDown').change(function () {
            var selectValue = $(this).val();
            var form = $('#newsArchiveForm');
            form.attr('action', form.attr('action') + '?year=' + selectValue);                 
            form.submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="newsArchiveForm" method="GET" action="http://www.a.com/myblog" novalidate="novalidate">
    <select id="newsArchiveDropDown" name="">
        <option value="2012" class="">2012</option>                                          
        <option value="2011" class="">2011</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Your form uses GET, that's probably overwriting any "manual" querystring parameters. Are you looking for POST by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply setting the `name` attribute to "year" on your select element can produce the intended result. The jQuery becomes much simpler too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newsArchiveDropDown').change(function () {
        $('#newsArchiveForm').submit();
    });
});
```

```
<form id="newsArchiveForm" method="GET" action="http://www.a.com/myblog" novalidate="novalidate">
    <select id="newsArchiveDropDown" name="year">
            <option value="2012" class="">2012</option>
            <option value="2011" class="">2011</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I am wondering if you know why mine is not working.

Comment: I'm afraid that has me a little stumped too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can occur if the none of the options were selected. Make sure you first select an option before proceeding.